# Changing list of dictionaries with list/dict comprehension_Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, list-comprehension, dictionary-comprehension

There is a dict:

```
facebook_posts = [
    {'Likes': 21, 'Comments': 2},
    {'Likes': 13, 'Comments': 2, 'Shares': 1},
    {'Likes': 33, 'Comments': 8, 'Shares': 3},
    {'Comments': 4, 'Shares': 2},
    {'Comments': 1, 'Shares': 1},
    {'Likes': 19, 'Comments': 3}
]
```

Please help someone, how to add key and value `{'Likes': 0}` if in dictionaries 'Likes' not exist, using list/dict comprehension way. Or in case it is not possible, advice alternative working way. Thanks in advance.

I have tried:

```
for post in facebook_posts:
    facebook_posts_new = [{'Likes': 0} for {} if not facebook_posts[post]['Likes'] in facebook_posts]
```

I'm expecting:

```
facebook_posts_new = [
    {'Likes': 21, 'Comments': 2},
    {'Likes': 13, 'Comments': 2, 'Shares': 1},
    {'Likes': 33, 'Comments': 8, 'Shares': 3},
    {'Likes': 0, 'Comments': 4, 'Shares': 2},
    {'Likes': 0, 'Comments': 1, 'Shares': 1},
    {'Likes': 19, 'Comments': 3}
]
```

Answer (score 1):

Use dict union operation `|` (if `Likes` is not among keys of a dict) within a list comprehension:

```
facebook_posts = [p | {'Likes': 0} if 'Likes' not in p else p 
                  for p in facebook_posts]
```

---

```
[{'Comments': 2, 'Likes': 21},
 {'Comments': 2, 'Likes': 13, 'Shares': 1},
 {'Comments': 8, 'Likes': 33, 'Shares': 3},
 {'Comments': 4, 'Likes': 0, 'Shares': 2},
 {'Comments': 1, 'Likes': 0, 'Shares': 1},
 {'Comments': 3, 'Likes': 19}]
```